# Showing Pdf From Different Server

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have got 2 Server 1. IIS Server (Internet Access), 2. File Server (No Internet Access) but both the server on the same network. I want to display the pdf from my File server but when i run the website using asp.net its works.. But When i host the website its doesn't show the pdf. The Page comes Blanks.. My Friend Told me that you need to use impersonation but after that also it dosen't work.. Any Help will be really appreciated on this.

(Asp.Net Development Server) :- Worked

[image]

After hosting the website in IIS When i view the website using my Internal IP Address It is not showing the Pdf Below is the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if you will have to use [UNC](http://www.uwplatt.edu/oit/terms/uncpath.html) to get your file.

It would be best if you could tell us what error are you getting on the hosted env.

I would also check : [Determining if file exists using c# and resolving UNC path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/458363/395890)

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply. I am not getting any error. Actually I Have tried UNC Path but its working on Asp.Net Development Server and After hosting the website on IIS When i view the website using my Internal IP Address It is not showing the Pdf Below is the screenshot

Comment: are you running the 2 urls from your machine? could it be that the hosted env does not have an adobe reader plugin for IE?