# C# How to Determine if Netwokr Path Exists w/o new Process

Tags: c#, vsto

I want to check if a certain network drive is accessible and exit my addin if not.  It's an Outlook 2013 addin in VSTO.  Anyway, I would like to search for it by UNC if possible as \192.168.0.2\WAN\ or I could use the drive letter as a last last resort, but not everyone uses the same letter for that drive in our company.

Anyway if I do `Directory.Exists("path with correct drive letter");` it hangs.  I want to just see if its there or not.

Can someone provide assistance and also give me a small example?

Oh and by the way, there is an answer where a process is spawned to do net use. I wanted to do it without spawning a new process wanted to know if it was possible.

Thanks a ton

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458363/determining-if-file-exists-using-c-sharp-and-resolving-unc-path

Comment: saw that one I wanted to do it without spawning another process.  fixed

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't spawn a process. Does it?

Comment: Have you tried to run a check on a secondary thread which you may cancel if it hangs?

Comment: it spawns one to run net use

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I', not sure how to do that do you have an example?  That would work for me as an answer too.

Comment: The simplest way is to use the BackgroundWorker component. See [How do I run a simple bit of code in a new thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363377/how-do-i-run-a-simple-bit-of-code-in-a-new-thread) for more information.

Comment: Also see the [How to: Create and Terminate Threads (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.90).aspx) in MSDN.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev if you just write those up a little I will accept answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a check on a secondary thread which you may cancel if it hangs. The simplest way is to use the BackgroundWorker component. See [How do I run a simple bit of code in a new thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363377/how-do-i-run-a-simple-bit-of-code-in-a-new-thread) for more information. Also see the [How to: Create and Terminate Threads (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4(v=vs.90).aspx) in MSDN.