# Accessing Network Path in Windows Service C#

Tags: c#, .net, file, service, windows-services

I have developed a windows service using local system as Account. I have used
network path of file

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"\\epm-server\penDocuments_LabMeds\" + Convert.ToString(dr["mrn"]) + "\\SyncedXML\\" + Convert.ToString(dr["xmlfile"]));
if (!fi.Exists)
    boolFileNotFound = true;
```

A dynamic path of a file that is built from database.

It works fine when I run Windows Service in Debug Mode, but when I install it then `fileNotExists` returns TRUE always like the file doesnt exist but infact it does exist.

This is bugging me a lot now. Kindly help me why its not working. Its a server path. Its getting opened in my PC.

Thanks

Comment: It works fine if I use it in a website. But its not working in a windows service.

Comment: So permissions then as @MitchWheat already said... Try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265953/c-how-can-you-easily-check-if-access-is-denied-for-a-file and also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458363/determining-if-file-exists-using-c-sharp-and-resolving-unc-path

Comment: I can access the path from my computer, So what could be the cause? On network what credentials do I need to use? Its a publically shared folder on  server.

Comment: @vickyshazad As already indicated, this is likely to be a permissions problem.  The user that your service is running as does not have access to the file you are attempting to access.  Either grant permission to you service user account, or use impersonation to access the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you notice the double backslashes in front and after SyncedXML (`\\SyncedXML\\`)?
This is probably the cause of your error.

Additionally I'd use string.Format in such cases to reduce the inadvertently addition of unwanted characters:

```
var path = string.Format(@"\\epm-server\penDocuments_LabMeds\{0}\SyncedXML\{1}", dr[mrn], dr[xmlfile]);
var fi = new FileInfo(path);
```

**Edit:**

If it's permission-related, then it's very likely that your local system account (in whose context the service is running) isn't allowed to access the epm-server.

The path is accessible if you're opening it directly or if you're running the service in debug mode as this is happening in your user context (e.g. *YOURDOMAIN\vickyshazad*), and you're allowed to access the ressource, whereas *NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM* is not.

It's usually a good practise to have a special service account for your developed windows service and grant this user only and exactly the required permissions (least privilege). Maybe ask your system administrator for a service user.

Local System (*NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM*) is a highly privileged account that's not recommended to use in general ([see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

> Most services do not need such a high privilege level. If your service does not need these privileges, and it is not an interactive service, consider using the LocalService account or the NetworkService account.

Comment: It didn't work either. Yes I can use string.Format. Thanks for that suggestion. Actually problem is with permission.