# Why System.IO.File.Exists doesn't take if else statement

Tags: vb.net, directory, file-copying, system.io.file

I have `if` condition issues when running the following code for an image file:

```
    Dim mainFolder As String = "\\Users\No_Image_Available.png"
    Dim saveDirectory As String = "\\IMAGE\"
    Dim Filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(mainFolder)
    Dim mainSavePath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(saveDirectory, Filename)

    If System.IO.File.Exists(mainSavePath) Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        'file doesn't exist
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("\\Users\No_Image_Available.png", "\\IMAGES\No_Image_Available.png")

    End If
```

If the file doesn't exist then it will accept the if statements by either `IF Not exist` or `IF exist`... however, if the file already exist it will take the copy argument whether it is in the right if condition or not.

Why is that? It is as if it still reads and accepts the first `'do nothing'` condition regardless.

FYI- the paths you see are fake

Comment: the problem is less like with `File.Exists()` than with the path/file name passed to it.  `the paths you see are fake`  provide real code for real answers

Comment: When referencing stackoverflow, someone got .Exist to work for them which is why I used it. That is the only one I know of so far to use. @Plutonix

Comment: Are you certain that the path to the file really exists. If you debug and copy `mainSavePath` and paste it in Explorer does the file really exist. It is possible your path may be off. What you are describing sounds exactly like the path is wrong.

Comment: @logixologist yes I debugged the real paths and they were correct and for Plutonix's comment: the paths I use are confidential(security reasons as to why I can't provide)

Comment: the image is created in path. It is just when the image is already there that it still tries to copy(which ultimately flags an error that image already exist)

Comment: `\\IMAGE\\\Users\No_Image_Available.png` how is that a valid path? Unless you made a typo when you tried to fake the path names.

Comment: all I am saying is double check the real path you are probably missing something.

Comment: @logixologist my real path is like `\\web-dav\Dev\web\WebUsers\Users\No_Image_Available.png"` and other one for `saveDirectory` is like `"\\web-dav\Dev\web\WebUsers\Ads\Classified_Ads_V2\IMAGE\"`

Comment: @logixologist also.. it tells me the file already exist in the location so it is reading the paths. So the .Exist is my issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83338/discussion-between-logixologist-and-narue1992).

Comment: From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx):`This method also returns false if path is Nothing, an invalid path, or a zero-length string. If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless of the existence of path.`

Comment: I just tested `System.IO.File.Exists(mainsavePath)` and it always throws `FALSE`. I have permissions in folder too so that can't be the issue :/ and I tested paths by adding them to windows explorer and they work. @Plutonix

Comment: not sure if it is because it is a server drive? before I use to use `Server.MapPath(~...)` for this path @Plutonix

Comment: can you try mapping a drive and trying a direct path like :G:\\Dev\web\...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining if file exists using c# and resolving UNC path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458363/determining-if-file-exists-using-c-sharp-and-resolving-unc-path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was that they were server directories. I made the corrections that worked.

```
Dim Filename = "No_Image_Available.png"
    Dim savePathcopy As String = Server.MapPath("~/IMAGES/")
    Dim pathToCheckCopy As String = savePathcopy + Filename

    'Dim mainSavePath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(saveDirectory, Filename)
    If (System.IO.File.Exists(pathToCheckCopy)) Then
        ' If System.IO.File.Exists(noImg) = True Then
    Else
        'file doesn't exist
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("\\..\Dev\web\WebUsers\...\..\Classified_Ads_V2\No_Image_Available.png", "\\...\Dev\web\WebUsers\...\..\...\IMAGES\No_Image_Available.png")
    End If
```

Comment: [Don't use .Exists like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265953/how-can-you-easily-check-if-access-is-denied-for-a-file-in-net)

Comment: Why so if I may ask? @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: woops my bad. Totally didn't see the link part XD ok I will review thanks! @JoelCoehoorn