# file Exists c# visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, file, local-system-account

Can not find the file and the file if it is in that route.

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"\\10.125.16.22\Facturas Electronicas\Factura EMP000098.pdf");
if (file.Exists)
{
    EventLog.WriteEntry("encontro los adjuntos de la factura " + nrodocumento);
    File.Copy(ruta, @"C:\Factura\" + file.Name + ".pdf", true);
    cantidad++;
}
else
{
    EventLog.WriteEntry("no existe el adjunto " + ruta);
}
```

when it reaches `if (file.Exists)` the result is `False`. The type of project that I am using is Visual Studio Service Project.

the service windows in the configuration I have `Account LocalSystem` I must change it ?

if it is not "Local System" which should I handle?

Comment: Well, does the file exist? Does the user-account the program is running under have permission to read that share?

Comment: Buenas. It is a shared folder, usually windows services are started under system account. Have you tried changing it to a specific user credentials?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining if file exists using c# and resolving UNC path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458363/determining-if-file-exists-using-c-sharp-and-resolving-unc-path)

Comment: if the file exists but does not recognize it

Comment: How do I give permission to this action?

Comment: it also depends on which user the service starts with

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/135867/how-to-grant-network-access-to-localsystem-account

Comment: @JuanR It's not a duplicate, the linked question involves similar code but doesn't mentions a service, that makes a huge difference in the outcome and the answer.

Comment: @Alejandro the linked question does not mention a service, but its the exact same proble. A window service by default does not run under a usser account that has rights to the shared resource so the root problem of the linked question and this question are the same. MYA must specify a user account to run the service that has rights on the shared resource. A domain user would be very easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the service windows in the configuration I have `Account LocalSystem` I must change it ?

Yes, you must change this. The `LocalSystem` account won't have any permissions for the computer at `10.125.16.22`. *This is true even if it's the same computer!* The UNC path will force a network access, and `LocalSystem` won't present any credentials over the network. Therefore `File.Exists()` will **always** return `false`, no matter the actual state of the file. This is covered at the end of [the Remarks section of the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks).

> The Exists method returns false if any error occurs while trying to determine if the specified file exists. This can occur in situations that raise exceptions such as passing a file name with invalid characters or too many characters, a failing or missing disk, or if the caller does not have permission to read the file.

Additionally, it's [almost always poor practice to use `File.Exists()` in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/265958/3043). Instead, just try to copy the file and handle the exception if it fails. You need to do this anyway, because there are **lots** of reasons a file copy might fail that have nothing to do with the file existing. This is also *faster*, because as slow as exception handling can be it's still usually much faster than the extra set of disk/network I/O operations invoked by the `File.Exists()` check.

Comment: As a thumb rule I try not to answer duplicated questions, dito for the quality of the answer tho.

Comment: I go ahead and answer if it's a very new user. This guy has been around 9 months, but it's only his third question. Also, while this could be a duplicate of a generic File.Exists() question or a network access question, you could make a case that putting the two together is unique, or rare enough to answer. Finally, I tend to give some credit for the language barrier, since that would make searching for duplicates or adapting a generic duplicate to his specific situation more difficult.

Comment: if it is not "Local System" which should I handle?

Comment: You need an actual user on the target system. This is easiest to accomplish in a domain environment, because the credentials must be accepted on _both_ systems.

Comment: The link in Rufus L's comment on the question will also be useful to you.