# How can I get for reading and writing Properties.Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired property?

Tags: c#, wpf, application-settings

In my WPF MVVM application I need to check if my application runs first after its installation. I had reviewed some examples in SO and in one of them - [how to check whether my c# window app is running first time after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8484436/how-to-check-whether-my-c-sharp-window-app-is-running-first-time-after-installated) I found the following code where the author recommended the use of UpgradeRequired:

```
// this must happen as soon as your program starts, before
// you do anything else with the settings
if (Properties.Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired)
{
    // upgrade FIRST, before doing anything else with the settings
    Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
    Properties.Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired = false;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

I quote here his words: "I also suggest adding a "UpgradeRequired" boolean to the settings which is by default true...." But when I try to add the same code in my App.xaml.cs file in OnStartUp event handler then the following error occured: "**Settings does not contain a definition for UpgradeRequired**" and UpgradeRequired was underlined with a red wavy line. I havn't faced with Properties.Settings before. So I'd like to know: Which assembly reference I should add to my application? What must I do to get access to Properties.Settings.Default.UpgradeRequired? our help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This not in any Assembly it's your oun custom settings. It's all explained here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: Thank you, MotKohn.