# File.Delete(mapPathName) doesn't work file is being used

Tags: c#, .net

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string mapPathName = Server.MapPath("\\images\\temp.jpg");
Uri uri = new Uri(mapLink);
webClient.DownloadFile(uri, mapPathName);
webClient.Dispose();
if (File.Exists(mapPathName))
    File.Delete(mapPathName);
```

I used the code above to download an encrypted image from Google Maps but after it was done downloading, I could not delete that file because it is being used.
Can anybody please help me to solve this?

ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhh. very sorry you guys, my mistake. The code above worked but when i tried to draw before delete and this time it does not work. >_< 
here is the code :

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
document.PageLayout = PdfPageLayout.SinglePage;
document.Info.Title = "Created with PDFsharp";

// Create an empty page
PdfPage page = document.AddPage();

// set size
page.Size = PageSize.A4;

// Get an XGraphics object for drawing
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string mapPathName = Server.MapPath("\\images\\temp.jpg");
Uri uri = new Uri(mapLink);
webClient.DownloadFile(uri, mapPathName);

// defind position to draw the image
XRect rcImage = new XRect(x + 30, y, 410, 300);

// draw the image
gfx.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.Snow, rcImage);
gfx.DrawImage(XImage.FromFile(Server.MapPath("\\images\\temp.jpg")), rcImage);

// save pdf file
string filename = "_HelloWorld.pdf";
string filePath = Server.MapPath(filename);
if (File.Exists(filePath))
    File.Delete(filePath);

document.Save(Server.MapPath(filename));

gfx.Dispose();
page.Close();
document.Dispose();

if (File.Exists(mapPathName))
    File.Delete(mapPathName);
```

Comment: This is by design. If you want to delete a file, stop using it.

Comment: @JonathanWood - where is it being used in the above code?

Comment: Why are you downloading it and immediately deleting it?  Is this test code?

Comment: @Maurice Reeves - yes this is just a test code. i am going to draw the image to a pdf file before i delete it. But i try to test deleting the image fisrt.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that there's something like anti-virus or other such security software that's checking the code after the download to verify it's not a threat?  I would consider temporarily disabling anti-virus and trying again to see if that's a culprit.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a particular reason you're calling `Dispose`?  This might be the cause.  If you insist on using dispose, try to delete it before you call dispose.  For example . . .

```
webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (o, s) =>
{
    //if (File.Exists(mapPathName)) discard, see Paolo's comments below . . .
       File.Delete(mapPathName);
};
webClient.DownloadFileAsync(uri, mapPathName);
webClient.Dispose();
```

Also have you considered the `using` clause?  This is usually prevents those kinds of errors from occurring.

Comment: The `DownloadFileCompleted` event is only invoked when using the asynchronous `DownloadFileAsync` method

Comment: Perhaps youre getting the error because it's still downloading and you're trying to delete it?

Comment: The `DownloadFile` method is a synchronous, blocking operation. There is no way that the file is still downloading after the method has finished.

Comment: Well that error usually occurs because it is still in the composition process.  anyway, if it is a local file then you can always use the FileWatcher to see watch for changes until the file is free.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/5695490c-a644-48a3-be2b-cfb762cf4765

Comment: Using `File.Exists` in this case is redundant, since no exception is thrown from `File.Delete` if the file to be deleted does not exist. It's almost never appropriate to check if a file exists before trying to use it (the operation is not atomic). Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673654/when-is-it-okay-to-check-if-a-file-exists) for more details.

Comment: that is a very interesting consequence . . .

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem. insteading using

```
gfx.DrawImage(XImage.FromFile(Server.MapPath("\\images\\temp.jpg")), rcImage);
```

i divided it into 2 line

```
var img = XImage.FromFile(Server.MapPath("\\images\\temp.jpg"));
gfx.DrawImage(img, rcImage);
```

and then

```
img.Dispose;
```

then i can delete the image :D thank you all.