# summing elements of a .txt file array in VB.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, average

College student in an advanced VB class who is turning to a forum for help - I've found a few examples of code but am having a hard time figuring this one out.. any and all help is appreciated :)

This application imports a .txt file stored in the bin, debug folder called data.txt
..20 records, 3 lines per record, the last line is the student's grade, I need to average the grades by summing each records grade and dividing by 20 and then displaying on the lstbox showing the average.

So far I've got..

```
    Dim objReader As IO.StreamReader
    Dim intFill As Integer
    Dim intCount As Integer = 0
    Dim intAverage As Integer
    Dim strLocationAndNameOfFile As String = "data.text"

    If IO.File.Exists(strLocationAndNameOfFile) = True Then
        objReader = IO.File.OpenText(strLocationAndNameOfFile)
    Else
        MsgBox("The file is not available. Restart the program when the file is avilable", , "Error")
        Me.Close()
    End If

    If IO.File.Exists(strLocationAndNameOfFile) Then
        objReader = IO.File.OpenText(strLocationAndNameOfFile)
        Do While objReader.Peek <> -1
            _strName(intCount) = Convert.ToString(objReader.ReadLine())
            _strItemID(intCount) = Convert.ToString(objReader.ReadLine())
            _intGrade(intCount) = Convert.ToInt32(objReader.ReadLine())
            intCount += 1
        Loop
        objReader.Close()
    End If

    For intFill = 0 To (_strName.Length - 1)
        *'intAverage = SUM OF ALL AVERAGES / LENGTH OF ARRAY -1*
        Me.lstAverage.Items.Add(intAverage.ToString())
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can see `Dim strLocationAndNameOfFile As String = "data.text"` working..

Comment: It looks like your college taught you to use type prefixes. You should have a chat with those professors... this used to be important, but is **no longer recommended**. See Microsoft's own coding style guidelines, especially [this section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) where they advise (in bold type no less) "Do not use hungarian notation".

Comment: Also, avoid `File.Exists()` http://stackoverflow.com/q/673654/3043 and since this is an advanced class, you should know to close your `objReader` object in a Finally block (possibly via a Using block).

Answer (score 1):

While looping to read the grades sum them up

```
    Dim total as Integer
    Do While objReader.Peek <> -1
        _strName(intCount) = Convert.ToString(objReader.ReadLine())
        _strItemID(intCount) = Convert.ToString(objReader.ReadLine())
        _intGrade(intCount) = Convert.ToInt32(objReader.ReadLine())
        total += _intGrade(intCount)
        intCount += 1
    Loop
```

And then just divide by 20 or _intGrade.Length

```
    intAverage = total / _intGrade.Length
```

Answer (score 1):

So many issues, as much as I loathe doing other's homework I want you to see what this could look like

```
Public Function GetAverageGrade(ByVal filename As String) As Double
    Dim totalGrade As Integer = 0
    Dim lineCount As Integer = 0
    Dim line As String

    Using rdr As New IO.StreamReader(filename)
       While (line = rdr.ReadLine()) IsNot Nothing
           lineCount += 1
           If lineCount Mod 3 = 0 Then totalGrade += Convert.ToInt32(line)
       End While
    End Using
    Return totalGrade / (lineCount / 3.0)
End Function
```

Of course, you probably want to do more with that data than just get the average grade. So an even better option is build code that reads it all in as a set of records:

```
Public Class GradeItem
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Item As String
    Public Property Grade As Integer
End Class
```

and then

```
Public Iterator Function ReadGradeItems(ByVal fileName As String) As IEnumerable(Of GradeItem)
    Using rdr As New IO.StreamReader(fileName)
        While rdr.Peek() <> -1
            Yield New GradeItem With {.Name = rdr.ReadLine(), .Item= rdr.ReadLine(), .Grade = Convert.ToInt32(rdr.ReadLine()}
        End While
    End Using
End Function
```

and now put it all together:

```
Dim grades As IEnumerable(Of GradeItem) = ReadGradeItems("data.text")

lstAverage.Items.Add(grades.Select(Function(g) g.Grade).Average())
```