# Is File.Exists considered harmful?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, file-io

I often use library functions like `File.Exists` to check for a file's existence before opening it or doing some other action.  While I have had good luck with this in practice over the years, I wonder if it is a poorly thought-out pattern.

Any IO call like a file system read can fail for multiple reasons. The path string could be wrong or the file actually not exist, you could lack permissions, someone else might have a lock that blocks you. You could even have another process or another user on the network move a file in the millisecond between your `File.Exists` and your `Open`.

Even if you get a successful result from `File.Exists`, you still really should enclose your actual open statements in a try block to handle one of the other possible failure modes.  If I am thinking about this correctly, `File.Exists` just lulls you into a false sense of safety if you use it instead of `Try` (as I am sure that I have on occasion in the past).

All of this makes it sound like I should abandon `File.Exists` and change whatever existing code I find to use the Try...Catch pattern only.  Is this a sensible conclusion? I realize that the framework authors but it there for us to use, but that does not automatically make it a good tool in practice.

Comment: If you guys think this is conceptual and should be on Programmers.SE feel free to migrate it.

Comment: i don't think it will throw exception

Comment: @EhsanSajjad correct in that File.Exists itself will not throw an exception, but it almost always precedes some other operation that can throw an exception.

Comment: Consider global exception handler for your application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is it okay to check if a file exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/673654/when-is-it-okay-to-check-if-a-file-exists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the answer completely depends on your specific reasons for using File.Exists.

For example, if you are checking a certain file path for arrival of a file, File.Exists could easily be the appropriate approach because you don't care what the reason for non-existence is.

However, if you are processing a file that an end user has requested (i.e. please import this excel file), you will want to know exactly why the file has failed. In this specific instance, File.Exists wouldn't be quite the right approach because the file existence could change between the time you check it and the time you open the file. In this case, we attempt to open the file and obtain a lock on it prior to processing it. The open method will throw the errors appropriate to the specific scenario that you are handling so you can provide the user more accurate information about the problem (i.e. another process has the file locked, the network file is not available, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

You should absolutely implement an exception handler for any code that could reasonably throw an exception and any I/O operation falls into that category.

That doesn't mean that using `File.Exists` is wrong though.  If there is a reasonable possibility that the file may not exist then prevention is more efficient than cure.  If the file absolutely should exist though, it might be more performant overall to suffer the occasional exception rather than take the hit of checking first every time.

Answer (score 3):

I use `File.Exists` in cases where the file *may not* exist under normal operating conditions (without something being broken in my system). If I know the file *should* exist (unless my system is broken), then I don't use `File.Exist`.

I wouldn't call this a "pattern" though. The best pattern is to consider what you're doing on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you how you want to handle the File not found. If you have used File.Exists to check if file is there or not, or you can also use  try catch block around your code and handle FilenotFound exception this will identify weather a file exists or not. Its purely up to you but I would prefer to check for File.Exists. It is same like checking null for accesing object rather than writing try catch around your code block and identify in catch that you object is null. It is always good to handle such validations at your end rather leaving it to c# try catch block.