# Java recognizes some files and directories but still thinks they do not exist

Tags: java, file

I'm using Java 17 on Windows 10 with NTFS. There is a file `A:\foo.bar` that shows up in a Java `Files.list()` operation, but that when I try to read it using Java, it throws a `java.nio.file.FileSystemException`:

> A:\foo.bar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

That's fine. There is another low-level process which has locked the file. When I turn off that other process, Java can access the file just fine. In fact even Robocopy, when trying to access this file, will skip the file (actually it will appear that Robocopy has copied the file, but it hasn't). So no mystery so far—another process is locking the file for exclusive access.

But here's the strange part. For the most part the file appears normal to Java:

- As I mentioned the file `A:\foo.bar` shows up in a `Files.list()` of `A:\`.
- If I call `Files.isRegularFile(fooBarFile)`, it returns `true` as expected.
- If I call `Files.isReadable(fooBarFile)`, it turns `false` as I might expect (and which is useful in this case).
- If I call `Files.readAttributes(fooBarFile, "*")` I see the attributes (timestamps, etc.).
- If I call `Files.readAttributes(fooBarFile, DosFileAttributes.class)` it returns the DOS attributes.

**But if I call [`Files.exists(fooBarFile)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) it returns `false`!** So it would appear that a file that is locked for exclusive access by another process will return `false` for `exists()`, which to me doesn't seem to follow the semantics of the `exists()` method as explained in its API.

As it is, it does seem useful to see if a file is not accessible by checking to see if `exists()` returns `false` yet `isRegularFile()` returns `true`; nevertheless that was unexpected and seems to be undocumented. Is this expected behavior? Is it documented? Does it work the same on other platforms, e.g. Linux?

Finally I note that [`Files.notExists(fooBarFile)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#notExists(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) returns `false` as well, so Java is not saying that the file is nonexistent, merely that it does not exist. Hmmm … the only way I can make that make sense is if `exists()` means "accessible", but the API contract for `exists()` does not talk about accessibility. The `notExists()` documentation adds:

> Note that this method is not the complement of the exists method. Where it is not possible to determine if a file exists or not then both methods return false.

That doesn't seem to apply to this situation either. So although this behavior is useful, it is unexpected, doesn't seem to be documented, and therefore I'm hesitant about relying too much on it. Can anyone provide more information or better yet authoritative documentation?

*Update:* A similar thing seems to happen with unreadable *directories*. For example the [`A:\System Volume Information` directory](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031120-00/?p=41753) is marked as "hidden" and "read-only" on Windows. It similarly throws a `java.nio.file.FileSystemException` exception if you try to access it. But `Files.exists()` returns `false`, even though `Files.isDirectory()` returns `true`! In fact it behaves exactly as the bullet points above, except that `isDirectory()` returns `true` instead of `isRegularFile()`.

Thus it seems like `Files.exists()` is duplicating `Files.isReadable()` (at least on OpenJDK 17 on Windows), even though that behavior doesn't seem to follow the `Files.exists()` API contract. Is this a JDK bug?

Comment: Perhaps `Files.isReadable` is a more useful check?

Comment: @Garret Wilson you may dig deeper into what is described on https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#notExists(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.LinkOption...)  `false if its existence cannot be determined`. Maybe because locked it can't be determined from the system

Comment: VGR, `Files.isReadable()` is useful, yes; here it returns `false`. (I'll update the question with that information.) I guess that only emphasizes the question: why is `exist()` acting like `isReadable()`? I would expect `exists()` to return `true` and `isReadable()` to return `false`.

Comment: Panagiotis, to your question, if Java can't determine whether the file exists or not, how can it still determine that it is a regular file? In other words, if it can't determine if it exists or not, I would expect `isRegularFile()` to return `false`. I guess I'm just trying to understand how the behavior meshes with the method semantics, and whether this is platform-dependent and/or JVM implementation dependent.

Comment: @GarretWilson could you provide a minimal reproduceable example? What is the process that makes this issue upon this file? Does it have anything to do with hyper-v ?

Comment: The program in question is [VeraCrypt,](https://veracrypt.fr/); when it has an `.hc` volume mounted, the file behaves as indicated (and RoboCopy skips it).

Comment: I updated the question to indicate this this happens to the `A:\System Volume Information` as well! This seems like buggy behavior to me.

Comment: Note that it *may* be that the JVM is asking it to the underlying file system.

Comment: @GarretWilson what is the file format that `A:\ ` uses ?

Comment: Panagiotis all these examples are using NTFS.

Comment: @GarretWilson could you please execute `Files.readAttributes(fooBarFile, DosFileAttributes.class, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);` and report any difference from `Files.readAttributes(fooBarFile, DosFileAttributes.class)` ?

Comment: @GarretWilson also give a try on `Files.isRegularFile(fooBarFile, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)` and check if there is any difference

Comment: @GarretWilson And in the end you can also verify the modified command `Files.exists(fooBarFile, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);`

Comment: Just try to open the file and cope with the exception as and when it occurs. All this futzing about with `exists()/notExists()/isReadable()/isDirectoy()notExists().isRegularFile()` is just a waste of time, and is also vulnerable to timing-window problems. The exception is still lurking and you still have to deal with it.  If you can't open the file, you can't open the file, and if you can you can. That's the only thing that actually matters. So do that, and nothing else. The best test for determining whether any resource can be used is simply to try to use it in the normal way.

Comment: @GarretWilson I believe I have provided the answer to the question explaining why this is not a bug, but a feature. If you agree, could you please accept the answer as to make the future readability of the thread more clear?

Answer (score 11):

> Thus it seems like Files.exists() is duplicating Files.isReadable()
> (at least on OpenJDK 17 on Windows), even though that behavior doesn't
> seem to follow the Files.exists() API contract. Is this a JDK bug?

### TL;DR

This is the way it was designed to behave and it follows the API contract. One major reason for why we have 2 methods, is that both methods return `true` if they are sure about the question.

- `Files.exist()` true means file definitely exists.
- `Files.notExists()` true means file definitely not exists.

But **false does not mean otherwise**. It could as well mean that the system can't determine the outcome and it returns false as the safest return if it can't throw such a checked exception.

- If you want to do some **action which is based on the condition that the file does not exist** in the system, **you should never use** `If (!Files.exists(file))` {...}. In this case let's say you want to create a new file and you want to make sure that another file does not already exist you **should always check with** `If(Files.notExists(file)){...}`
- On the other side if you want to do some **action which is based on the condition that the file exist** in the system, **you should never use** `If (!Files.notExists(file))` {...}. In this case let's say you want to read/modify a file and you want to make sure that the file already exist you **should always check with** `If(Files.exists(file)){...}`

### Analytical explanation

I believe the java API [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) of `Files.exists(fooBarFile)` could be a bit better, although the java API [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#notExists(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) for `notExists` is a bit clearer for this in the following:

> Note that this method is not the complement of the exists method.
> Where it is not possible to determine if a file exists or not then
> **both methods return false**.

Here is what I suspect is going on.

According to the method description

```
//  @return  
// {@code true} if the file exists; 
// {@code false} if the file does not exist or its existence cannot be determined.
public static boolean exists(Path path, LinkOption... options) {
        if (options.length == 0) {
            FileSystemProvider provider = provider(path);
            if (provider instanceof AbstractFileSystemProvider)
                return ((AbstractFileSystemProvider)provider).exists(path);
        }

        try {
            if (followLinks(options)) {
                provider(path).checkAccess(path); <-------------- if no options provided this is executed
            } else {
                // attempt to read attributes without following links
                readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class,
                               LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
            }
            // file exists
            return true;
        } catch (IOException x) {
            // does not exist or unable to determine if file exists
            return false;  <----- AccessDeniedException is causing return false
        }

    }
```

If someone inspects the code he will see the meaning of `@return {@code false}... or its existence cannot be determined.`

could be further explained from the line of `.checkAccess(path)` which mentions in the API doc:

```
 * @throws  AccessDeniedException
 *          the requested access would be denied or the access cannot be
 *          determined because the Java virtual machine has insufficient
 *          privileges or other reasons. <i>(optional specific exception)</i>
```

So in case a `AccessDeniedException` is thrown which is also a subclass of `FileSystemException` (which also the questioner is getting from another command during file read), then `Files.exists(fooBarFile)` is supposed to return `false` because of that exception which does not allow the JVM to determine if the file definitely exists.

Question also mentions:

> Files.**notExists**(fooBarFile) returns false as well

which I think originates also from the same point.

```
public static boolean notExists(Path path, LinkOption... options) {
        try {
            if (followLinks(options)) {
                provider(path).checkAccess(path);  <---------- If no options provided this line executes
            } else {
                // attempt to read attributes without following links
                readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class,
                               LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
            }
            // file exists
            return false;
        } catch (NoSuchFileException x) {
            // file confirmed not to exist
            return true;
        } catch (IOException x) { 
            return false;   <------ In case of AccessDeniedException or some other IOException the return is false.
        }
    }
```

Which verifies that both methods `exists` and `notExists` are designed to return `false` in case `AccessDeniedException` or some other `IOException` is thrown, as this would be translated into , JVM **can't determine if the file exists or not**.

So each method gives **the safest return it could give** in this uncertain condition, considering it can't throw such an exception. So in case

- it is `exists()` it returns `false` if it can't determine, so that the developer would not be sure that the file exists and move forward with actions such as reading the file.
- it is `notExists()` it returns `false` if it can't determine, so that developer would not be sure that the file does not exist and move forward with actions such as creating a new file.

So both methods shall be used appropriately and trusted for a definite answer **only if they return `true`**. `false` does not mean negative answer to `exists` or `notExists`. And someone should never be based on the outcome of `!Files.exists(file)` and `!Files.notExists(file)`, at least as a logical inversion of the answer of the method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673654/when-is-it-okay-to-check-if-a-file-exists