# How do I search through directories recursively?

Tags: c#, recursion

I need to change a lot of file names all in the same way. They all share a common root but are scattered through out that root in other folders. I am trying to write a program in c# that starts at the root and recursively goes through all of its children and either changes file names or goes into the next folder.  Here is what I have:

```
public void cascade(string path)
    {
        if(IsDirectoryEmpty(path) == true) 
        { }
        else
        {
            String[] childFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
            String[] childFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            ChangeFileName();

            for (int p = 0; p < childFolders.Length; p++)
            {
                cascade(childFolders[p]);
            }
        }
    }
```

A button calls to cascade and passes in the initial root directory. I then found someones method they wrote to check if its empty:

```
public bool IsDirectoryEmpty(string path)
    {
        return !Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(path).Any();
    }
```

Im trying to change the fileNames everytime I enter a new directory and if there are more folders I enter them to change more file names. It isnt working and I have no clue why. Changing the file names works but this method isnt reaching all of the folders.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching for file in directories recursively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830069/searching-for-file-in-directories-recursively)

Answer (score 0):

The functionality exist, it will implement the `Enum SearchOption.AllDirectories`.  This will trigger the recursive functionality:

```
var directories = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

You can also do the same thing for `DirectoryInfo` with some slight modification.

> searchOption Type:
>
> System.IO.SearchOption One of the enumeration
>   values that specifies whether the search operation should include only
>   the current directory or all subdirectories.

More information about this can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327(v=vs.110).aspx).

Important note, once you've obtained the list of those directories you can loop through and modify in whatever manner you would like.  You'll also want to implement the `File.Move` if your simply renaming your file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method. Pass the root directory in the function as the parameter.

```
void DirSearch(string sDir) 
{
try 
{
   foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)) 
   {
    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, txtFile.Text)) 
    {
       ChangeFileName();
    }
    DirSearch(d);
   }
}
catch (System.Exception excpt) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive functions are hard to debug. You can try a non-recursive version like this:

```
    public void ChangeAllFiles(String root)
    {
        Stack<String> searchStack = new Stack<string>();
        searchStack.Push(root);

        while (searchStack.Count > 0)
        {
            String path = searchStack.Pop();
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
            {
                ChangeFileName(file);
            }

            foreach (var subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
            {
                searchStack.Push(subDir);
            }
        }
    }
```

If that doesn't work: What folders are missing?

Answer (score 0):

this one should do the trick.

```
public void cascade(string path)
{
    String[] childFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path);
    if(childFiles.lenght > 0)
    {
        String[] childFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(path); 
        ChangeFileName(childFiles); //iterate and change each fileName

        for (int p = 0; p < childFolders.Length; p++)
        {
            cascade(childFolders[p]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This only looks in sub-directories if there are also files present in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the changeFiles method to accept a path as an arguement. Then in the cascade method I passed the change files method the path that was passed to the cascade method.

```
public void cascade(string path)
    {
        if(IsDirectoryEmpty(path) == true) 
        { }
        else
        {
            String[] childFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
            String[] childFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            ChangeFileName(path);

            for (int p = 0; p < childFolders.Length; p++)
            {
                cascade(childFolders[p]);
            }
        }
    }
```