# Search within subforlder if a file exist

Tags: c#

I have a folder named A which has subfolders A1, A2 and A3. Each of these subfolders contain a folder named B. I want to seach the subsfolders of A which are A1, A2 and A3 for the B folder and if it exist I want to get from that folder the latest file path.

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\app\A\A1\B");

var myFile = directory.GetFiles()
             .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
             .First();
```

I wan to avoid using the directory var and search instead.

Comment: you are right i fixed it

Comment: So what have you tried? "C# find subdirectories" yields plenty of results.

Comment: Did you check the syntax of the method you already use? It has several overloads. (very strong hint)

Comment: I taking a look at the moment. I am close.

Comment: This question in essence is searching recursively for a specific folder/file. which already exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830069/searching-for-file-in-directories-recursively

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetDirectories()` method in Directory class with the wildcard character `"*"`. This wildcard will list all the directories under the current directory.

So an example is like this:

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\app\", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (string dir in dirs)
{
    Response.Write(dir + "<br>");
}
```