# "Illegal characters in path" error using wildcards with Directory.GetFiles

Tags: c#

I have a directory with multiple sub directories that contain .doc files. Example:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\testenviroment\Released\test0.doc
C:\Users\user\Documents\testenviroment\Debug\test1.doc
C:\Users\user\Documents1\testenviroment\Debug\test2.doc
C:\Users\user\Documents1\testenviroment\Released\test20.doc
```

I want to get all the `test*.doc` files under all Debug folders. I tried:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\user", "*Debug\\test*.doc",
    SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

And it gives me an "Illegal characters in path" error.

If I try:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\user", "\\Debug\\test*.doc",
    SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

I get a different error: "Could not find a part of the path C:\Users\user\Debug".

Comment: If the path is like `C:\Users\user\Documents` why are you searching in `C:\Users\user\Debug`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Yes you can. Acc. to MSDN `The search string to match against the names of files in path. This parameter can contain a combination of valid literal path and wildcard (* and ?) characters (see Remarks), but doesn't support regular expressions.` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There are certainly illegal characters in your path. Nothing is wrong with your search string/

Comment: My bad. Yes, actually didn't look well enough. The wildcard is correct which is what makes the problem interesting at first sight.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are including a folder within the search pattern which isn't expected. According to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f(v=vs.110).aspx):

> searchPattern Type: System.String The search string to match against
>   the names of files in path. This parameter can contain a combination
>   of valid literal path and wildcard (* and ?) characters (see Remarks),
>   but doesn't support regular expressions.

With this in mind, try something like this:

```
String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\user", "test*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                 .Where(file => file.Contains("\\Debug\\"))
                 .ToArray();
```

This will get ALL the files in your specified directory and return the ones with `Debug` in the path. With this in mind, try and keep the search directory narrowed down as much as possible.

Note:

My original answer included [EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233(v=vs.110).aspx) which would work like this (making sure to pass the [search option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx) (thanks @CodeCaster)):

```
String[] files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Users\user", "test*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                 .Where(file => file.Contains("\\Debug\\"))
                 .ToArray();
```

I've just run a test and the second seems to be slower however it might be quicker on a larger folder. Worth keeping in mind.

Edit: Note from `@pinkfloydx33`

> I've actually had that practically take down a system that I had
>   inherited. It was taking so much time trying to return the array and
>   killing the memory footprint as well. Problem was diverted converting
>   over to the enumerable counterparts

So using the second option would be safer for larger directories.

Comment: Possibly better to use DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles to make use of the enumerable-ness of the return value. Otherwise all results are returned up front which can cause issues on directories with large number of files

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Was adding an example with that in mind as you commented :)

Comment: I've actually had that practically take down a system that I had inherited. It was taking so much time trying to return the array and killing the memory footprint as well. Problem was diverted converting over to the enumerable counterparts.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thanks, good to know. I've added that comment to the answer so people are clear about which option to use.

Comment: Though the folders had file counts several orders of magnitude larger than what you would expect from a "typical" folder. Switching to enumerable also benefits when you add the Where extension method like you did and should prevent iterating the files twice (once to get, second for where)

Comment: "user" appears to be a placeholder for the actual account name. Just hope that the username isn't "Debug" - it is not beyond the realms of possibility.

Comment: I'd imagine the second is more memory-efficient, but has to do a filesystem query every time, so it's slower, while the other... well, it definitely at least does it all at once, then stores the results in a List. I dunno if that'd speed it up. Which you use depends on what you need.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I agree which is why I left both examples there. It really depends on the use case I think.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter, the search pattern, works only for filenames. So you'll need to iterate the directories you want to search, then call `Directory.GetFiles(directory, "test*.doc")` on each directory.

How to write that code depends on how robust you want it to be and what assumptions you want to make (e.g. *"all Debug directories are always two levels into the user's directory"* versus *"the Debug directory can be at any level into the user's directory"*).

See [How to recursively list all the files in a directory in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929276/how-to-recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-in-c).

Alternatively, if you want to search *all* subdirectories and then discard files that don't match your preferences, see [Searching for file in directories recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830069/searching-for-file-in-directories-recursively):

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\user", "test*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
               .Where(f => f.IndexOf(@"\debug", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

But note that this may be bad for performance, as it'll scan irrelevant directories.