# Getting Illegal characters in path while accesing long file paths

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to search for a file with a given name from a given root directory using the code below

```
Dim searchPattern As String = fileNameWithoutExtension.TrimEnd & "*"
Dim foundFiles As String() = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine("\\?", directoryPath),
searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

I am able to do this without any issues when I run the vb.net application from visual studio. But, getting the below error when I running it as a published Windows application.

```
Illegal characters in path.
Stack Trace
at
System.Security.Permissions.FilelOPermission.EmulateFilelOPermission Checks(String fullPath)
at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator 1..ctor(String path, String original UserPath,
String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler 1 resultHandler, Boolean
checkHost)
at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String SearchPattern,
SearchOption searchOption) at Fluence PanelSchedule.ProjectDocumentCreator.SearchFile(String
projectName, String docName, List 1 tempArrayFilesNotFound) Source::
\\?\C:\Users\username\directoryA\10_Document files.
```

The prefix `\\?\` is added to avoid longer file path issues. And there is no other special character present in the file path.
What am I missing here?

Comment: This is what \\?\ is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats#dos-device-paths.  Also, I'm not a fan of creating paths using concatenation.

Comment: @dbasnett Thanks for the response. I went through the document that you have mentioned. I couldn't really get what is the issue with my approach. And why is that happening?  The code runs well as a vb.net application on visual studio but fails when the same is published as a windows application.

Comment: Is it failing on the development PC or a different computer? If the latter, which version of .NET Framework is installed where it fails, assuming it's using .NET Framework and not .NET Core or .NET - \\?\ only works in .NET Framework 4.6.2 and later.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It is failing on the same development PC. The PC has .NET version 4.8+

Comment: @ManjunathM What is the value of the SearchPattern parameter? Maybe it is going wrong in the way mentioned in ["Illegal characters in path" error using wildcards with Directory.GetFiles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42531393/1115360).

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's going as "fileName*" (file name followed by *)

Comment: @ManjunathM Does it still complain if you *don't* add the \\?\ ?

Comment: @AndrewMorton If I don't add it, some files (I have a huge set of files to be searched for) are not being fetched as the total file path is more than 260 characters.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by using Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.File's Directory.EnumerateFiles() method, instead of System.IO's methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle this long path issue I have used the AlphaFS library, as it provides enhanced file system functionality with support for long paths. ( Which can be easily installed via the NuGet package manager in Visual Studio)

```
Imports Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem
...Other code
Dim fileNameWithoutExtension As String =Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName.Trim())
Dim searchPattern As String = fileNameWithoutExtension & "*"
Dim files As IEnumerable(Of String) =Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath,
searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Also using `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` over `Directory.GetFiles()` sounded better as the number of files to be searched and processed is in the hundreds.

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)