# How can I find all the .cs files types in the Assets?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void OnInputChanged(string searchString)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            foreach (var asset in AssetDatabase.FindAssets("*.cs"))
            {
                readTextFile("", asset);
            }
        }
     }
```

I tried this :

```
foreach (var asset in AssetDatabase.FindAssets("*.cs"))
```

but it didn't find any .cs files to search in. I want to find all the cs files also in root and in all subfolders in the Assets.

This doesn't seems to work :

```
AssetDatabase.FindAssets("*.cs")
```

Comment: Can't you just use `var asset = AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:script", null);`

Comment: If the goal is reading files(not as assets) you can also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830069/searching-for-file-in-directories-recursively

Comment: @TEEBQNE you suggest is almost the same as I did few minutes ago : string[] assetsPaths = AssetDatabase.GetAllAssetPaths();  the problem in both cases it's getting all the scripts or if later I filter only for cs files in the assets that are also in the unity packages.  and Idon't want it to search/get the scripts in the packages. is there a way to tell it in the script to skip scripts/cs files that are in packages ?

Comment: @DanielLip The second parameter in the `FindAssets`, is the folder in which the search will start. Set it to the parent of your project's folders. It will skip all of the packages. I believe something along the lines of `("t:script", new[] {"Assets"})` should work.