# Subfolder count in PS via C#?

Tags: powershell, subdirectory

I am trying to reliably get the subfolder count in a PowerShell script. I am avoiding `Get-ChildItems` due to its slowness and instead trying to use C#.  See the picture.  The syntax seems OK for files but not subfolders.  The correct counts are returned for files, but not for folders. It's probably a simple fix, but it is rather annoying.

[image]

Code sample:

```
ForEach ($SubDir in ($DirObjects | ?{$_.PSIsContainer})){
    $NoOfex4Files = [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($SubDir.FullName, '*.ex4')| Measure-Object| %{$_.Count}
    $NoOfmq4Files = [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($SubDir.FullName, '*.mq4')| Measure-Object| %{$_.Count}
    $NoOfSubFolder = [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateDirectories($SubDir.FullName,'*')| Measure-Object| %{$_.Count}
    #$NoOfSubFolder= [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]::new($SubDir.FullName)::GetDirectories| Measure-Object| %{$_.Count}
```

Comment: You can refer this one if you are using C# [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830069/searching-for-file-in-directories-recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830069/searching-for-file-in-directories-recursively)

Comment: Please don't post code in pictures. Make a minimal example and post it in text

Comment: Small sample code provided - should be self explanatory

Answer (score 0):

```
#SOl 1 $NoOfSubFolder = [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateDirectories($SubDir.FullName, '*','TopDirectoryOnly')| Measure-Object| %{$_.Count}

## NOT THIS $NoOfSubFolder= [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]::new($SubDir.FullName)::GetDirectories| Measure-Object| %{$_.Count}
#SOL2 $NoOfSubFolder= (Get-ChildItem $SubDir.FullName -Recurse -Directory | Measure-Object).Count
#SOL3 $NoOfSubFolder = Get-ChildItem $SubDir.FullName -Recurse |? { $_.PSIsContainer } |Measure-Object |select -Expand Count
```