# Check for access rights on a folder using C#

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, filesystems, access-control

I need check if a specific user (Domain or Local), has mentioned rights (Read / Write) on the given directory.

The method should return true even the User is inheriting the rights from User Group (like Administrators).

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22020271) works fine but it is limited to Current User only

Answer (score 1):

Try the bellow function

```
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl; 

     public static bool CheckWritePermissionOnDir(string path)
        {
            var writeAllow = false;
            var writeDeny = false;
            var accessControlList = Directory.GetAccessControl(path); Control
            if (accessControlList == null)
                return false;
            var accessRules = accessControlList.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
            if (accessRules == null)
                return false;

            foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in accessRules)
            {
                if ((FileSystemRights.Write & rule.FileSystemRights) != FileSystemRights.Write)
                    continue;

                if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow)
                    writeAllow = true;
                else if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Deny)
                    writeDeny = true;
            }

            return writeAllow && !writeDeny;
        }
```

Comment: but this does not check for a particular user

Comment: you can use this line  SecurityIdentifier users = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinUsersSid, null); and then add the if inside your foreach statement like (if(rule.IdentityReference == users) before you check the rights