# Access to file is denied

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I am running an image gallery project and I want to get all .jpg files from the D:\ drive so I saw this code

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFile(@"D:\", "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

But I get this error message of UnauthorizedAccessExeption Access to the path ... is denied.

Please is there a way I can search through all the sub folders of D:/ excluding the paths which dont have access permission. Because other users too wont have to edit the file permission

Comment: If the access to the path is denied, you probably need to give the user who executes the code the appropriate access to the path.

Comment: There are file access methods in C# IO; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226208/check-for-access-rights-on-a-folder-using-c-sharp) for an example; this is for write but could be adapted. Also reference to other answers with more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Directory.GetFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2), the error UnauthorizedAccessException is caused by the following:

> The caller does not have the required permission.

Also, I wouldnt run GetFiles with search option as AllDirectories but go through one directory at a time. I used this link:

[UnauthorizedAccessException cannot resolve Directory.GetFiles failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393178/unauthorizedaccessexception-cannot-resolve-directory-getfiles-failure)

Answer 2 (not the accepted one)

Comment: Okay, but how to recognise and skip that instance?