# Getting files from my drive returns 0 in c#

Tags: c#

I am just a newbie to VS, C# and XAML.
I have this project am building which I want to display all images in my `D;\` drive. So I actually got this code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098011/directory-enumeratefiles-unauthorizedaccessexception) and luckily for me I had it working without any difficulty. I can tell the code is working because my app now takes about 2 minutes to start up, so its been delayed due to the searched images

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetDirectoryFiles(string rootPath, string patternMatch, SearchOption searchOption)
{
    var foundFiles = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    if (searchOption == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<string> subDirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(rootPath);
            foreach (string dir in subDirs)
            {
                foundFiles = foundFiles.Concat(GetDirectoryFiles(dir, patternMatch, searchOption));
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
        catch (PathTooLongException) { }
    }
    try
    {
        foundFiles = foundFiles.Concat(Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootPath, patternMatch));
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { }
    return foundFiles;
}
```

I use this line of code to call the function `GetDirectoryFiles`

```
string[] filePaths = {};
string[] extObj = { "*.JPG", ".JPEG", ".PNG", ".GIF", ".BMP*.jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif", ".bmp" };
foreach(var ext in extObj)
    filePaths.Concat(GetDirectoryFiles(@"D:\", ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(filePaths.Length);
```

But am having an issue... When the `filePaths.Length` is outputted I get `0`. I don't actually know why but I know I have at least 4000 `.jpg` images in my `D:\` drive, so I shouldn't be getting 0.

My question in a nutshell: I want to load all images in my `D:\` drive excluding the paths which returns an `UnauthorizedAccessException` and `PathTooLongException` error in reference to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158110/access-to-file-is-denied)

Comment: You're passing the same file extension twice for no reason: the search pattern is not case sensitive. You'll get back the same file twice. You also have a type here: `".BMP*.jpg"`. See if that's actually a typo just here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Concat` extension method returns a new enumerable object but you're not doing anything with it.  You need to assign it back to `filePaths`.

First, change the type of filePaths.  If you keep it as an array, you'll have to keep reifying it (e.g. calling `ToArray`) each time and that's costly.

```
IEnumerable<string> filePaths = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
```

Then, assign each new enumerable back to filePaths.

```
foreach (var ext in extObj)
    filePaths = filePaths.Concat(GetDirectoryFiles(@"D:\", ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
```

Finally, filePaths is `IEnumerable<string>` so you have to use `Count()` instead of `Length`.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(filePaths.Count());
```

...or just reify it...

```
string[] finalFilePaths = filePaths.ToArray();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(finalFilePaths.Length);
```

Answer (score 5):

try

```
    foreach(var ext in extObj)
        filePaths= filePaths.Concat(GetDirectoryFiles(@"D:\", ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
```

you forgot to assign the result of concat to the same source