# C# getdirectories().Length UnauthorizedAccessexception

Tags: c#, directory

Using 'Directory.GetDirectories().Length'

Except for an UnauthorizedAccessexception folder, 
How can I get the number of folders?
I would like to get only the number of Accessible folder.

sorry, I can't speaking english well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using Directory.GetDirectories() you can get a list of directories and then check permission for each directory and if it's allowed than take one counter for a number of the accessible folders.

To check permission on folder go to the following link.
Visit [Checking for directory and file write permissions in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281620/checking-for-directory-and-file-write-permissions-in-net)