# In Labview 2012, Windows 7 OS, how can user write permission be verified?

Tags: windows, file-permissions, labview

While developing Labview code for a Windows 7 operating system, it became apparent the system which the software is used may be set up to not allow a common user write access to a selected folder.  If the selected folder does not have write permission, the code needs to prompt the user to select a different folder.

So far I have Labview 2012 and found the Get Permissions block under advanced file functions.  Is this the best way to determine if a user has write permission?  Does a better way exist to test for write permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Get Permissions** does not return accurate results on Windows.

I just tried it on some subfolders of `C:\Users` on my Windows 7 machine and it returns `111111111` (binary) for all user folders - indicating that I should have full read and write access - even though Windows won't actually let me write to any user's folder other than my own.

Meanwhile `C:\Users\Public` returns `101101101`, implying no write access, but I **can** write to that folder.

My understanding of Windows file and folder permissions in a network environment is that it can become very complex, with different policies applied in different places, and the best way to find out if you can write to a location is to try and write there and catch the error.

Comment: This oddball behavior is exactly what I was curious about.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @nekomatic. I just updated my post. Apparently this problem is not only for Labview users: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281620/checking-for-directory-and-file-write-permissions-in-net

Comment: @MarcoM that's a good link, if only to illustrate that it's complicated - you should edit that into your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Some people simply try to create a dummy file, handling the error and notifying it to the user if it's the case (and removing the dummy file if the creation succeeds).

Please note this is not a Labview related problem:
give a look [here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281620/checking-for-directory-and-file-write-permissions-in-net) and on a [thread I've just started on NI Labview Forum](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Get-Permissions-Vi-reliability-Windows-7/m-p/3308756).