# Exception Folder: Access to the Path is denied

Tags: c#, access-denied

I am using the following code to access 4 folders. However, there is 1 folder which is private and only seniors have access to it. How can I avoid that folder and still access the other 4 folders?

```
class Program
{
    const string FILENAME = @"H:\Personal\text.xml";
    const string FOLDER = @"F:\Apps";
    static XmlWriter writer = null;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Indent = true
        };

        writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
        writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);
        WriteTree(info);

        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Return");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

**EDIT:** (WriteTree Code)
I have added the rest of the code which also includes the WriteTree code.
I do not have access to the management folder.

```
    static long WriteTree(DirectoryInfo info)
    {  
    long size = 0;
        writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
        try
        {
            writer.WriteAttributeString("name", info.Name);
            writer.WriteAttributeString("numberSubFolders", info.GetDirectories().Count().ToString());
            writer.WriteAttributeString("numberFiles", info.GetFiles().Count().ToString());
            writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());


            foreach (DirectoryInfo childInfo in info.GetDirectories())
            {
                size += WriteTree(childInfo);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
            writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
        }

        FileInfo[] fileInfo = null;
        try
        {
            fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
            writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
        }

        if (fileInfo != null)
        {
            foreach (FileInfo finfo in fileInfo)
            {
                try
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("name", finfo.Name);
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("size", finfo.Length.ToString());
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    size += finfo.Length;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}", finfo.FullName, ex.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                    writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
                }
            }
        }

        writer.WriteElementString("size", size.ToString());
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        return size;

    }
  }
 }
```

**Error**: 
Exception Folder: Error: Access to the path is denied.

Comment: Show code of WriteTree method

Comment: You can wrap the folder/file access in a try...catch block to gracefully fail in the cases the user has no access to the folder.

Comment: Using `try catch` to log error folders, and continue on the others folders?

Comment: Also if it's an option for you, your app can request elevated privileges so that it has access to the necessary folder at run time.

Comment: We need to see the `WriteTree` method, this is presumably where the error occurs. You might be able to `try ... catch` or you could have a list of excludes.

Comment: First of all remove all catch(Exception) or catch{}.  Catch only those exceptions you expect to get. For example, catch(UnauthorizedAccessException) as posted by @EFAV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the permissions before write the file with richardwiden's answer : [Checking for directory and file write permissions in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281620/checking-for-directory-and-file-write-permissions-in-net)

Or you could use `try catch` in your `WriteTree()` function to ignore the `UnauthorizedAccessException` exception like :

```
try {
    writer.WriteAttributeString("name", info.Name);
    [...]
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // If is a permission error, ignore exception
    if (ex is UnauthorizedAccessException)
         return size;

    // custom error log
    string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
    writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
}
```

Comment: Catch exactly on method you expect it: 
    writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
    writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
    DirectoryInfo info = null;    try { 
 info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER); } catch(UnauthorizedAccessException e){}
if(info!=null)    WriteTree(info);

    writer.WriteEndDocument();
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();     Otherwise you can get execption from XmlWriter.Create for example, which is not related to directory access

Comment: Are you sure is `new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);` which make the exception ? Maybe it is `WriteTree(info)` function ...

Comment: I checked DirectoryInfo.ctor - it does not throw UnauthorizedAccess. So as you said it is necessary to wrap only writetree method. Btw, where did you get information about UnauthorizedAccessException - could you please post it in too

Comment: I +ed your post, but he added WriteTree to original question. Everything became useless now)

Comment: @Sim Yes you already use a try catch in `WriteTree` function. I updated my answer

Comment: @EFAV that worked! However its only displaying that theres 6 folders. It doesn't mention the subfolders anymore!

Comment: @Sim So you have another problem in your algorithm. Adding only this two lines `if (ex is UnauthorizedAccessException) return size;` should not change your program behavior. Make a new topic if needed and feel free to accept my answer checking the green tick. Thnaks