renaming folders and files in large file tree
I have a large file tree with around 954,000 files. There are tons of files that I need to rename back to the original, symbols were removed from the original file name and replaced with a number code ie "#" replaced with "0023" and "- modified" at the end of the file name.
I have the following powershell script that works on one path destination on the files successfully.
# Define the path where you want to perform the renaming
$path = "C:\Path\To\Your\Directory"

# Get all files in the directory
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -File

foreach ($file in $files) {
    # Check if the file name ends with "- modify" (case-insensitive)
    if ($file.Name -like "*- modify*") {
        # Remove "- modify" and replace "0023" with "#" in the file name
        $newFileName = $file.Name -replace "- modify", "" -replace "0023", "#"

        # Construct the full path for the new file name
        $newFilePath = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath $newFileName

        # Rename the file
        Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName $newFilePath

        # Output the change for verification
        Write-Output "Renamed file: $($file.FullName) to $newFilePath"
    }
}


Would it be possible to run a powershell script to run from the root folder and going through all folders and nested folders to fix folder and files names with the corrected paramters?

I have some files and paths that go past the 255 character file path limit. Does powershell still work in these cases?


I have tried building out the code but keep running into errors:
# Define the path where you want to perform the renaming
$rootPath = "C:\Path\To\Your\Directory"

# Function to rename items based on the criteria
function Rename-Items {
    param (
        [string]$itemPath
    )

    # Get all items (files and directories) in the path
    $items = Get-ChildItem -Path $itemPath

    foreach ($item in $items) {
        # Check if the item name contains "- modify"
        if ($item.Name -like "*- modify*") {
            # Remove "- modify" and replace "0023" with "#" in the item name
            $newName = $item.Name -replace "- modify", "" -replace "0023", "#"

            # Construct the full path for the new name
            $newItemPath = Join-Path -Path $item.DirectoryName -ChildPath $newName

            # Rename the item
            Rename-Item -Path $item.FullName -NewName $newItemPath

            # Determine if the item is a directory or file
            if ($item.PSIsContainer) {
                Write-Output "Renamed directory: $($item.FullName) to $newItemPath"
            } else {
                Write-Output "Renamed file: $($item.FullName) to $newItemPath"
            }
        }
    }
}

# Function to recursively rename items in all nested directories
function Process-Directories {
    param (
        [string]$directoryPath
    )

    # Rename items in the current directory
    Rename-Items -itemPath $directoryPath

    # Get all subdirectories
    $subdirectories = Get-ChildItem -Path $directoryPath -Directory

    # Process each subdirectory
    foreach ($subdirectory in $subdirectories) {
        Process-Directories -directoryPath $subdirectory.FullName
    }
}

# Start processing from the root path
Process-Directories -directoryPath $rootPath


IME Power shell has nice cmdlets for handling folders and recursion, but becomes very slow when handling large file trees. My solution has been to implement folder recursion in my script, leaving Powershell to handle just one folder at a time. I believe this is down to Powershell caching the file paths and filling up system memory.

I've had issue with Net library with large number of files.  Found best way to handle a large number of files is to write a recursive algorithm that gets one folder at a time without using -Recursive.  When you have large number of files you often will get out of memory errors.

Here is sample of c# code to get all files recursively one folder at a time : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74531791/c-sharp-find-a-specific-file-anywhere-on-local-drives  Code catches all exceptions and continues when an error occurs.

Your code might be simplified greatly by just using -Recurse and \\?\ to handle Maximum Path Length Limitation. Get-ChildItem also already has an integrated -Filter that can handle wildcards. See also Using delay-bind script blocks with parameters to get a better understanding on how the renaming is performed in this case.
# NOTE: \\?\ is important to handle Maximum Path Length
$initialPath = '\\?\C:\Path\To\Your\Directory'
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $initialPath -Filter '*- modify*' -Recurse -File |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '0023', '#' -replace '- modify' } -Verbose


I suspect your code is not finding all the files because of exceptions. I would run code below to see if it finds all the files and if any exception are reported.  My code continues after an exception is found.  I think you code terminates when the first exception is found.
You can modify my code to rename the files instead of outputting to the xml file.
I converted my c# code to powershell so you can see how to recursively get files from each folder. Code creates an xml file with results.
using assembly System.Xml
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

Function WriteTree
{
    Param ([System.IO.DirectoryInfo]$info, [System.Xml.XmlWriter]$writer)
    begin{
        $size = [long]0;
        $writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
    }
    process{
        try
        {

            $writer.WriteAttributeString('name', $info.Name);
            $writer.WriteAttributeString('numberSubFolders', $info.GetDirectories().Count.ToString());
            $writer.WriteAttributeString('numberFiles', $info.GetFiles().Count.ToString());
            $writer.WriteAttributeString('date', $info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
             
            foreach ($childInfo in $info.GetDirectories())
            {
                $size += WriteTree -info $childInfo -writer $writer;
            }
                
        }
        catch
        {
                $errorMsg = [string]::Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", $info.FullName, $_);
                Write-Host $errorMsg;
                $writer.WriteElementString('Error', $errorMsg);
        }

        $fileInfo = $null;
        try
        {
            $fileInfo = $info.GetFiles();
        }
        catch
        {
            $errorMsg = [string]::Format('Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}', $info.FullName, $_);
            Write-Host $errorMsg;
            $writer.WriteElementString('Error',$errorMsg);
        }

        if($fileInfo -ne $null)
        {
            foreach ($finfo in $fileInfo)
            {
                try
                {
                    $writer.WriteStartElement('File');
                    $writer.WriteAttributeString('name', $finfo.Name);
                    $writer.WriteAttributeString('size', $finfo.Length.ToString());
                    $writer.WriteAttributeString('date', $info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                    $writer.WriteEndElement();
                    $size += $finfo.Length;
                }
                catch
                {
                    $errorMsg = [string]::Format('Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}', $finfo.FullName, $_);
                    Write-Host $errorMsg;
                    $writer.WriteElementString('Error', $errorMsg);
                }
            }
        }

        $writer.WriteElementString('size', $size.ToString());
        $writer.WriteEndElement();
        return $size;
    }
    end{}
}

$filename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$folder = 'c:\temp'
$writer = $null

$settings = [System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings]::new();
$settings.Indent = $true;

$writer = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($filename, $settings);
$writer.WriteStartDocument($true);

$info = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]::new($folder);

WriteTree -info $info -writer $writer;

$writer.WriteEndDocument();
$writer.Flush();
$writer.Close();
Read-Host 'Enter Return'

