Recursively getting the size of all files in a directory - works for first 30 lines?
get-childitem -Recurse -force -directory | ForEach-Object {$myfile = $_
    new-object psobject -property @{
       Fullname = $myfile.fullname
       CreationDate = $myfile.CreationTime
       MyOwner = (get-acl $myfile.fullname).owner
       MyModified = $myfile.LastWriteTime
       MySize = (gci -path $myfile -FILE -Recurse| measure Length -sum).SUM
      }
    } | format-table Fullname, CreationDate, MyOwner, MyModified, MySize

Tried on two different computers.  One in a corporate environment and one gamer station at home.
Example output that shows "blank" directories without errors.  When it is blank, it still does the math but does not return folder size.  The folders are not empty.   Math is correct for the folders that are returned.  Strange part is, its in sequence, not based on contents of the folder.
Fullname                                   CreationDate MyOwner MyModified      MySize
--------                                   ------------ ------- ----------      ------
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\.tmp.driveupload                                   125520818
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\3dprinting                                               103
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\books                                               26234390
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\bots                                                   51098
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\bpygrabs                                              615136
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\chatgpt shots                                           7243
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\Coll                                                18360395
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\cookbook                                             5543004
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\cookbook2                                           73856963
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\cookbook3                                          156979899
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\D&DCharacter                                      3247213518
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\Desktop                                          28269197775
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\desktop backg...                                   601815372
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\driver                                             205022601
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\Edit for jass...                                    51424797
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\eve                                                 11253163
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\family videos...                                 70274775414
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\FFMPEG conver...                                  1060820989
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\google sync                                          2148013
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\gopro w conve...                                  4266188662
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\WhileyCharacter                                    121764451
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\library                                             10418218
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\linux                                            15268294073
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\OneLastShot                                          4327529
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\PolyBridgeGIFs                                        941186
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\PS edit                                             60264250
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\pythonchallenge                                       206918
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\Saves                                                6493563
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\SCA                                                   340697
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\servershots                                           103002
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\sienna                                               8580300
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\StableDiffusion                                     76908221
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\Starfield                                           77494988
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\stfc                                                 4025738
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\batman keys                                             3874
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\WorkPresentation                                    12855913
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\Writing                                               357455
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\cookbook\kare...                                            
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\cookbook\TOC ...                                            
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\cookbook\kare...                                            
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\cookbook3\pdf                                               
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\cookbook3\va                                                
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\cookbook3\pdf...                                            
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\cookbook3\pdf...                                            
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\D&DCharacter\...                                    26234390
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\D&DCharacter\...                                            
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\D&DCharacter\...                                            
C:\users\BBurner\desktop\D&DCharacter\...                                            


What is the problem, exactly? You are not detailing what you are actually getting nor what you were expecting to find. Also I suggest to use calculated properties with Select-Object instead of making new PSCustomObject with ForEach-Object

This [mcve] looks fine to me (although the embedded gci -Recurse might get very expensive, there are definitely other ways to do this). I wonder whether this is exactly how you tested it? Or are there any error suppressions or Try/Catch blocks around it knowing that some files in your whole? (launched from C:\ ?) system might not be accessible. You might add a Write-Host $myfile.fullname to script to figure out which folder is last accessed and probably causing the issue.

You must be getting an exception and script is exiting as soon as first exception occurs.  Exceptions with get-childitem occur when you do not have permission to read a file or folder.

See my answer at following with handles the exceptions and continues : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78800097/renaming-folders-and-files-in-large-file-tree/78800278#78800278

Other answers here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080654/a-powershell-script-to-find-the-file-size-and-file-count-of-a-folder-with-millio

What's the error message?  Calculating the size of every subdirectory is pretty time and resource expensive.

Try to add -EA Continue to both get-childitem and gci call to continue (but report) on errors.

EA Continue gives the same result.  These are all folders owned by the current users with NTFS modify,  run under administrator context.
Emphasis on: no error message.

Try adding the -Depth parameter to get-childitem.  It may be set too small by default.

Same result, but thanks for the suggestion.
