# Search for file and delete it, not knowing the path C#

Tags: c#

Been working on a school project and I'm kinda stuck.
I've been trying to write something like this, however it doesn't work. Is there any way to look for a file, delete it, but not knowing the exact path of the file?

```
var files = new List<string>();
                
foreach (DriveInfo d in DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(x => x.IsReady == true))
{
    files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(d.RootDirectory.FullName, "x.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
}

if (File.Exists(files)) 
{
    File.Delete(files);
}
```

Comment: `foreach(var file in files)` ?

Comment: you can recursively iterate through all directories of a drive, check the filename if it corresponds to the target file name and then delete it.

So you need a method that goes through a file list and calls itself when it hits a directory

Comment: So in short, my teacher is gonna hide few .jpg files, he will give me the name of these, however pc im working on has multiple drives, and he isn't going to give me the exact path name.
So the program has to look for every possible drive on pc and delete x.jpg.

Comment: yeah, recursion does the trick here: https://code-maze.com/csharp-basics-recursion/

And System.IO.FileInfo

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a good problem description. Do you have compiler errors, runtime exceptions, unexpected results? Please specify with exact error messages

Comment: @MichaelGabbay depends if they want to delete all jpgs or a specific one called x, the question seems to imply the latter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is

```
if (File.Exists(files)) 
{
    File.Delete(files);
}
```

files is not a file path its a list of them

you need to do

```
foreach(var file in files)
{
    if (File.Exists(file)) 
    {
        File.Delete(file);
    }
}
```

A simpler way of doing the same thing would be

```
var files = from d in DriveInfo.GetDrives()
            where d.IsReady
            from f in d.RootDirectory.EnumerateFiles("x.jpg",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            select f;

foreach(var file in files)
{
    if (file.Exists) 
    {
        file.Delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: It compiled, but apparently it has no right to access Documments and files

Comment: you either need to add a check for access rights or just use try catch to skip folders and files you don't have access to

Comment: here is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281620/checking-for-directory-and-file-write-permissions-in-net

Comment: let's say the x.jpg is located in .../project/images/x.jpg

where "..." is drive.

Is there anyway to look for files actually knowing the path, but not the exact drive?