# C# populating treeview and getting errors on directories that I do not have permission to read

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, treeview

I am populating a treeview control, c# visual studio 8, using this code:

```
private TreeNode TraverseDirectory(string path)
    {
        TreeNode result = new TreeNode(path);
        foreach (var subdirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
        {
            result.Nodes.Add(TraverseDirectory(subdirectory));
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The trouble is that if I click on, say the c:/ drive I get an error on directories that I do not have permission to read.  My question is, how do I avoid showing those directories that I do not have permission for?  How would I test for that and then tell the app to ignore them?

Thanks R.

Comment: use a try/catch is one possibility

Comment: Thanks, i'll talke a look at this tomorrow, getting tired :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simplistic approach:

```
TreeNode result;
try {
    string[] subdirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
    result = new TreeNode(path);
    foreach(string subdir in subdirs) {
        TreeNode child = TraverseDirectory(subdir);
        if(child != null) { result.Nodes.Add(child); }
    }
    return result;
} catch (FindTheSpecificException) {
    // ignore dir
    result = null;
}
return result;
```

*personally* I'd try and do some kind of lazy loading, but IIRC this involves adding dummy nodes with the standard `TreeView`.

Comment: Thanks Marc i'll have a go at this tomorrow as its getting late and the brain power is getting low... :)

Answer (score 0):

As for testing, I think this previous question covers it: [how can you easily check if access is denied for a file in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265953/c-how-can-you-easily-check-if-access-is-denied-for-a-file)

As for telling the app to ignore it, simply put your call to `result.Nodes.Add()` inside your test condition block, so if the permission does not exist, no node is added. If you decide to go with `try...catch`, make sure you're swallowing the right `SecurityException`, because there are other exceptions that could occur here, but that's it.