# FileSystemObject.FileExists returns false even if I map server path

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

The FileExists object keeps returning false even if I use the following:

```
If fso.fileExists(Server.MapPath(thumbfile)) Then %><img src="<%=thumbfile%>" /><% Else %><img src="./images/no-pic.gif" /><% End If %></div>
```

I am able to navigate to it locally. It is hosted on IIS6, what permissions are required on the server mapped directory?

To debug I did this:

```
<% Response.Write (Server.MapPath(thumbfile)) %>
```

This returned (which is valid):

```
\\101.101.101.123\docs\729\pic.jpg
```

The files are located on server 101.101.101.123 but IIS is on server 101.101.101.124

FileExists is still returning false.

```
<% Response.Write (thumbfile) %>
```

returns:

```
pdf/729/pic.jpg
```

Where PDF is a VIRTUAL DIRECTORY mapped to the listed path with Read/Write/Execute

```
\\101.101.101.123\docs
```

Comment: [First mistake is using File.Exists() at all.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265953/how-can-you-easily-check-if-access-is-denied-for-a-file-in-net/265958#265958)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a UNC path mapped to a drive letter then this won't work. Although **your** interactive account has the drive letter mapped, the account that the website runs under most likely won't.

Mapped drive letters are account specific.

Comment: Kev, I've edited the original question, are we saying what I have done is not possible?

Comment: @kaybee - what is in the `thumbfile` value before you `MapPath()` it?

Comment: I have updated the original question with the information requested.

Answer (score 0):

I guess adding the following command in the user's logon script, who is set in "Log on As:" option of IIS service should resolve the issue.

```
net use x: \\SERVERNAME\SHARENAME
```