# How do I check if an access to a string path is denied?

Tags: c#, file-access

i want to know how i can test if i can access a string path or not. Here is the code I use:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namescpace prog1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = @"C:\Users\Admin";
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            foreach (FileInfo fil in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                //At dir.GetFiles, I get an error  saying
                //access to the string path is denied.

                Console.WriteLine(fil.Name);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to test if acces is denied (to string path)
Then do the GetFiles and all that.

I've already found this: [how can you easily check if access is denied for a file in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265953/how-can-you-easily-check-if-access-is-denied-for-a-file-in-net)

Any help?

Comment: Can you not just wrap it in a try/catch block?

Comment: You can catch the Exception... If you got the exception => You don't have access...

Comment: Would catching UnauthorizedAccessExceptions be too much of a overhead, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest (and usually safest) option is to just do what you're doing now, but wrap the code in proper exception handling.

You can then catch the [UnauthorizedAccessException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception.aspx) from `GetFiles` (and potentially a `SecurityException` from the `DirectoryInfo` constructor, depending on the path) explicitly, and put your handling logic there.

Answer (score 2):

Can do something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     string path = @"C:\Users\Admin";
     DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path); 
     FileInfo[] files = null;
     try {
            files = dir.GetFiles();
     }
     catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex) {
         // do something and return
         return;
     }

     //else continue
     foreach (FileInfo fil in files )
     {
        //At dir.GetFiles, I get an error  saying
        //access to the string path is denied.

         Console.WriteLine(fil.Name);
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: AccessDeniedExpection does not exist in my context, what can I do?

Comment: @MátéHomolya: corrected, it's a [UnauthorizedAccessException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception.aspx)

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it with this try/catch thing. This was new to me.