# Can not delete files from Recent folder

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a Software that can delete Temporary files, Prefetch data, files in Recent folder and so on. My problem is I can delete files from Temp folder successfully, but when I try for Recent folder, an exception is thrown, "Access to path...is denied". 
PS: According to some other questions, I have set File attributes to normal, but still no luck. Please help me on this issue. For your better understand, I put some code here:

```
public Boolean CleanRecentData()
{
        isAllClean = true;
        String SysRecentPath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\Recent";
        DirectoryInfo SysRecDir = new DirectoryInfo(SysRecentPath);
        File.SetAttributes(SysRecentPath, FileAttributes.Normal);

foreach (FileInfo fi in SysRecDir.GetFiles())   //Access Denied 
                                                 //Exception is thrown here
        {
            try
            {
                fi.Delete();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                recentLogLines.AppendLine(ex.Message);
                isAllClean = false;
            }
        }

        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in SysRecDir.GetDirectories())
        {
            try
            {
                dir.Delete(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                recentLogLines.AppendLine(ex.Message);
                isAllClean = false;
            }
        }

        return isAllClean;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried running your executable with admin permissions?

Comment: Also, FYI, I suggest not just logging ex.Message, but rather ex.ToString().

Comment: @MarcF, Thanks but I have tried with Admin permission. My User name in Win7 has admin privilege. I can delete any other file, but can not delete any file from Recent folder

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to access the Recent folder via Windows Explorer?

You could go ahead and change the permissions in your system, but NOT in your users systems.
Therefore you could handle this exception condition in two ways.

1. You need to  check if you have file access before accessing, using [FileIOPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.aspx) but this might be redundant and wasteful if you are doing it on too many files.
2. Just try to open the file and put your effort into a good exception handler if it fails
   [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/265958/1218809)

Comment: I can't access the Recent folder now from Win Explorer.