# How can i check for access denied when getting files?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void DirSearch(string root, string filesExtension,string textToSearch, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] filePaths = null;
            int numberoffiles = 0;
            int numberofdirs = 0;
            try
            {
                filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(root, filesExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                string ad = err.ToString();
            }
            if (filePaths != null && filePaths.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
                {
                    _busy.WaitOne();
                    if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        return;
                    }

                    List<MyProgress> prog = new List<MyProgress>();
                    int var = File.ReadAllText(filePaths[i]).Contains(textToSearch) ? 1 : 0;
                    if (var == 1)
                    {
                        string filename = filePaths[i];//filePaths[i].Split('\\').Last();
                        numberoffiles++;
                        prog.Add(new MyProgress { Report1 = filename, Report2 = numberoffiles.ToString() });
                        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, prog);
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                    numberofdirs++;
                    label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                                {
                                    label1.Text = numberofdirs.ToString();
                                    label1.Visible = true;
                                });
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm using try and catch the problem is that once one of the directories is access denied the program stop. And i want it to continue to the next directory.

If in filePaths for example i have 450 files in 10 directories and in the second directory it's access denied then continue to the next directory and so on.

Comment: What's with the Sleep()? If you are going to use BackgroundWorker then convention is to use ReportProgress() instead of Invoke()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Few suggestions for you**

- You should enclose the read process inside a `try.. catch` block. so that Access-Denied Exception will throw if the specified file is not accessible.
- use `restrictedFiles` to Keep Track of the skipped files.
- Use `continue;` in catch to continue the iteration.

Let me rename the variables as well for better understanding; Now consider the code

```
void DirSearch(string rootDirectory, string filesExtension, string textToSearch, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
     List<string> filePathList = new List<string>();
     List<string> restrictedFiles = new List<string>();
     // Other Inits
     try
     {
         filePathList = Directory.GetFiles(rootDirectory, filesExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
     }
     catch (Exception err)
     {
         string ad = err.ToString();
     }
     foreach (string file in filePathList)
     {
         try
         {
             // Code before
             int var = File.ReadAllText(file).Contains(textToSearch) ? 1 : 0;
             // it will throw exception if it is not accessible
             // Your code after
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
             restrictedFiles.Add(file);
             continue;
         }
     }
     // restrictedFiles will contains all restricted files @ the end of iteration
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to catch the `UnauthorizedAccessException` that your `File.ReadAllText(...)` call is making. Surround that reading operation in a `try/catch` and use the `continue` keyword when an exception is thrown. You could try and [check for accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265953/how-can-you-easily-check-if-access-is-denied-for-a-file-in-net) , but that may not be entirely accurate.